# Group array of objects depending on values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects

```
[
  { values: [2, 7, 1] },
  { values: [1, 2, 7] },
  { values: [7, 1, 2] },
  { values: [3, 4, 5] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
]
```

I want to group these objects together with the other object with same values. So this array of objects should be grouped into 3 groups since the first 3 objects have the same values, the next object is alone and the last 2 objects have the same values.

As seen in the example, the values can have different orders, but should still be considered the same.

I am thinking about for each element to loop through the remaining elements and see if they are alike, but it will result in `O(n^2)`.

I guess I should remove elements from the array that has already been grouped.

So how could I, efficiently, group it as

```
[[first, second, third],[fourth],[fifth,sixth]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var data = [
  { values: [2, 7, 1] },
  { values: [1, 2, 7] },
  { values: [7, 1, 2] },
  { values: [3, 4, 5] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
];

var hash = {};
for(var obj of data) {
  var key = obj.values.sort().join("-");
  if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
  hash[key].push(obj);
}
var result = [];
for(var k in hash) result.push(hash[k])
console.log(result)
```

Or js6 variant:

```js
var data = [
  { values: [2, 7, 1] },
  { values: [1, 2, 7] },
  { values: [7, 1, 2] },
  { values: [3, 4, 5] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
];

var hash = data.reduce((hash, obj) => {
  const key = obj.values.sort().join("-");
  if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
  hash[key].push(obj);
  return hash;
}, [])

var result = Object.keys(hash).map(k => hash[k])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yeah it's great. I actually don't care about the keys. Is it possible to give them other keys (such as 1, 2, 3) and remove those with empty arrays in the `values` property? I know I could use `.filter(function (obj) { return obj.values.length > 0; })...` but is it efficient enough to call `obj.values` multiple times?

Comment: @Jamgreen about ```.filter()``` i guess it's not related question but I don't see why it's not efficient. Of course it depends on your data nature and volume

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `forEach()` loop and `sort()`

```js
var arr = [
  { values: [2, 7, 1] },
  { values: [1, 2, 7] },
  { values: [7, 1, 2] },
  { values: [3, 4, 5] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
  { values: [2, 1, 8] },
];

var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  var s = [].concat(e.values).sort().join('|');
  if (!this[s]) {
    this[s] = [e.values];
    result.push(this[s]);
  } else {
    this[s].push(e.values)
  }
})

console.log(result)
```